# How to print out Multi-Dimensional Arrays in php

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, foreach

Consider the array is:

```
Array
    (
    [Page-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-1
                    [1] => Item-1
                )
        )
    [Page-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-2
                    [1] => Item-2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-3
                    [1] => Item-3
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-4
                    [1] => Item-4
                )
        )
    [Page-3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-5
                    [1] => Item-5
                )
        )
    [Page-4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-6
                    [1] => Item-6
                )
        )
    [Page-5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-7
                    [1] => Item-7
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-9
                    [1] => Item-9
                )
        )
    [Page-6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cat-8
                    [1] => Item-8
                )
        )
)
```

Where, the first keys [Page-x] from array will be *Main-Links* in the navigation menu.
Some of the main links may have Sub-Links, some not.
Sub-links are the values of the key [0] of the 3rd sub-array.
And finally the URL for each and every link will be the value of key [1] of the 3rd sub-Array.

Only Pages that have more than one category will show its categories as sub-links

The navigation bar i would like to have:

```html
1. <a href="Item-1">Page-1</a>
2. <a href="#">Page-2</a>
     <a href="Item-2">Cat-2</a>
     <a href="Item-3">Cat-3</a>
     <a href="Item-4">Cat-4</a>
3. <a href="Item-5">Page-3</a>
4. <a href="Item-6">Page-4</a>
5. <a href="#">Page-5</a>
     <a href="Item-7">Cat-7</a>
     <a href="Item-9">Cat-9</a>
6. <a href="Item-8">Page-6</a>
```

the PHP code

```php
$records = $p->main_links();

foreach ($records as $key => $value) {
    $return[$value['page']][] = array($value['child'], $value['item']);
}

foreach ($return as $key2 => $value2) {

    $count = 0;

    /* Select a specific value within the Array */
    $main_links = $value2[$count][1]; /* URL of the main Pages */

    $count = count($return[$key2]);

    if($count > 1) {
        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
        {
            $link_name = $value3[0]; /* Child Link Names */
            $link_url  = $value3[1]; /* URL of Child Links */

            /* addedd htmlspecialchars() function to $variables that will be echoed into HTML. It provides some XSS protection */                
            $cat_link .= '<li><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($filter1.$p->seoUrl($key2).$filter2.$p->seoUrl($link_url)).'">'.htmlspecialchars($link_name).'</a></li>';
        }

        $result .= '
            <li '.htmlspecialchars($li_class).'><a href="#"><span>'.htmlspecialchars($key2).'</span></a>
                <ul>
                    '.$cat_link.'
                </ul>
            </li>';
    }else {
        $result .= '
            <li><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($filter1.$p->seoUrl($main_links)).'"><span>'.htmlspecialchars($key2).'</span></a></li>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately i can't get it work... the output is not what i am expecting :(
current Output (wrong one):

```html
1. <a href="Item-1">Page-1</a>
2. <a href="#">Page-2</a>
     <a href="Item-2">Cat-2</a>
     <a href="Item-3">Cat-3</a>
     <a href="Item-4">Cat-4</a>
3. <a href="Item-5">Page-3</a>
4. <a href="Item-6">Page-4</a>
5. <a href="#">Page-5</a>
     <a href="Item-2">Cat-2</a>
     <a href="Item-3">Cat-3</a>
     <a href="Item-4">Cat-4</a>
     <a href="Item-7">Cat-7</a>
     <a href="Item-9">Cat-9</a>
6. <a href="Item-8">Page-6</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Careful... use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data used in the context of HTML so that you don't enable script injection, and invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Thank you brad, i will do that!

Comment: It seems the question has nothing to do with PDO

Comment: what is the result you are getting with your current structure.

Comment: I recommend you add `parent_id` and `order` columns or structure it as a [MPTT](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) so you can handling nesting and levels.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I though i mention PDO because that might return a different structured array than a mysql_fetch_array would do, but i might be wrong. Should i remove PDO from the title?

Comment: PDO can fetch results in many different ways - see the [documentation on PDO fetch styles](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters)

Comment: @larsAnders okay, i am using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`: To return next row as an array indexed by column name

`array(6) { 
 [0]=> array(7) { 
         ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
         ["page"]=> string(6) "Page-1" 
         ["pID"]=> string(1) "1" 
         ["category"]=> string(5) "Cat-1" 
         ["catID"]=> string(1) "1" 
         ["item"]=> string(6) "Item-1" 
         ["icatID"]=> string(1) "1" } 
}`

What i would like to do next is to group all the Pages that appear more than once in the Title field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another way around which is way better than the one i was trying to do. This solved my case.

http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/articles/web-programming/single-query-dynamic-multi-level-menu

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is close to working. This line will always produce a count of 1.

```
$count = count($value);
```

What you're looking for there, I believe, is:

```
$count = count($return[$key]);
```

Comment: Did that produce the result you were after?

Comment: No. What i suspect that the first `foreach()` loop customizes the array, and the rest of the data from other columns are not included. I get results only from `title` and `category` columns. I think that first loop should be customized in a different way, that will group `title` column and forward all of the other information. If i had that maybe i could assign the URL from `item` data for each page.